# Work with SQL table in SharePoint environment

Tags: 2013, sql, datatable

I have to create a simple custom list with half a dozen of columns, but due to number of items it will create (there will be more then 5000), OOTB SP custom list will bread after 5000 items threshold is reached. Then, I thought of external list, but I found out external list is not so great as it lacks a couple of things, like SPD workflow cannot be associated to it.

What looks least problematic is to show SQL table somehow on custom data table view (example of data table view [here](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.rs/2017/07/display-sharepoint-list-or-library-in.html)).

Any suggestion if this sounds ok or what could be optimized solution to display and work with data from SQL table in SharePoint?

Comment: I do not have anything to do with this company, nor their products but I'm using a company called Layer2 's solution called "Business Data List Connector". Work's like a dream to import data from SQL table to a SharePoint list.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want any third party applications or solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable treshold for the list. Real limit for list is 30 million items. 
Treshold is only for items displaying in views, not for storing data.
I dont think u should invent something

Comment: removing treshold is not an option for me.

Comment: There is a lot articles, what to do. 
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Answer (score 0):

The list view threshold is just for the query you are using to show data associated with the list.  You can have millions of items in a SP list.  You should [Index](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19671.sharepoint-2010-indexed-columns.aspx) your columns to avoid the threshold errors.  This is considered best practices for large list storage anyways.  There is no need to do anything extra, just use what is available.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did try indexing columns, and I succeeded but as soon as I go over 5000 items, I can't create new items. I can view/filter/edit/etc. with list items but I can't create new items.